# Why is my code giving incorrect results for big numbers?

Tags: java

I am trying to solve this task:

> In this exercise you will write a program that estimates the value of π. Pretend that we are looking at a dartboard in the picture above. If the square is 2units wide and 2 units high, the radius of the circle within the square is 1 unit. Then the area of the circle is  π*r2 = π*12 = π. The area of the square will be 2*2 = 4.
>
> The estimation of π will work by randomly “throwing darts” at the dartboard. We will assume that every dart will hit the board but the location of that strike will be random so some darts will land inside the circle and some will land outside the circle. The calculation of π is then the ratio of the number of darts that land inside the circle to the total number of darts, multiplied by 4. Note that as we increase the number of darts used in the simulation, the accuracy improves.
>
> Follow the steps to complete the program:
>
> 1. Declare variables that represent x, y coordinates of a dart, the distance of the dart from the origin, the number of darts that land inside the circle, and the total number of darts.
> 2. Read in the total number of darts (N) from the user and create an instance of the Random class.
> 3. Create a loop that runs N times. Inside the loop, you will use the nextFloat() method of the Random class to create x, y coordinates randomly, and then compute the distance of the dart from the origin. Determine whether the dart lands inside or outside of the circle.
> 4. Compute π using the estimation algorithm.
> 5. Run the program with increasing numbers from 100 to 100,000,000 and observe the accuracy of π.

Here is my program I wrote. It works to some extent, but results seems incorrect for input like 100000. Can anyone explain what's wrong with my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class calculatePI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x;
        double y;
        double distance;
        int i = 0;
        float inside = 0;
        float outside = 0;
        float totalDarts;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();

        System.out.println("Enter the number of darts: ");
        totalDarts = scan.nextFloat();

        for (i = 1; i < totalDarts; i++) {
            x = Math.abs(random.nextFloat() % 2);
            y = Math.abs(random.nextFloat() % 2);

            distance = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - 1, 2)
                    + Math.pow(y - 1, 2));

            if (distance <= 1)
                inside++;
            else
                outside++;
        }

        System.out.println("Total number of arrows inside circle:" + inside);
        System.out.println("Estimated value of Pie: "
                + (((inside * 4) / (double) totalDarts)));

    }

}
```

Comment: okay well I get the desired result but only for certain inputs of darts. the program is working but when I put values close to 100000 and I don't know why. I just need some insight as to what to do

Comment: if I put a value like 100000000 I get nothing close to pi.

Comment: Include these informations in your question (not everyone reads comments).

Comment: Integer overflow. Your int entered is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE, which happens to be 2147483647 or 0x7fffffff, which is a little over 2 billion.

Comment: But im not entering an integer im entering a float. the instructions specify to use nextFloat

Comment: oh wait..... i is increasing to the value of the float point correct? so i should change int i; to float i; ?

Comment: It doesn't matter since your **for-loop** uses ints, and so you're overflowing the loop. Sorry about my first comment by the way. Retracted, and 1+ to your question. I would use longs for the for loop. Never use a floating point number as a loop index.

Comment: Not that it solves anything but what are you trying to achieve with `random.nextFloat() % 2`? `nextFloat` will never return value greater than 1 (it returns value in range 0.0[inclusive] - 1.0[exclusive]) so `%2` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks guys im getting it to work better now. I think I got it where it should be. And yeah I realized I never changed that. I erased the %2 and changed it to nextDouble. Is that okay?

Comment: This was my first post. Sorry guys. Thanks for all the help! My code is working great now. Thanks for editing the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem change types of

```
float inside = 0;
float outside = 0;
float totalDarts;
```

to either `int` or `long`.

Problem with `float` is that not all integers can be represented precisely by this type. `float` uses 24 bits to store number (rest of bits are used to store sign, and precision) which means that without loss of precision `float` can store `int` values only in range `-16777216` to `16777216`.

You can observe this with

```
System.out.println(16777216f);
System.out.println(16777217f);
System.out.println(16777218f);
```

which prints

```
1.6777216E7
1.6777216E7
1.6777218E7
```

Now you see that `16777217` can't be represented precisely and will be represented with `16777216`. This means that `16777216f+1` will still return `16777216F`, which blocks your `totalDarts` from being greater number than `16777216`, which causes problem for bigger numbers.